# How can I know that whether user has received the pop up dialog for location access permission check or not in Android?

Tags: android

I am having a Google map in fragment where I am fetching the current location of user. When I am.using the fragment in one of my activities,  whenever the activity will load Everytime it is showing the pop-up dialog to take the permission for location access from user. How to make sure that user should get the permission pop-up dialog for accessing the current location only once. Please help I am strucked here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if you need to ask for the permission first, as the [documentation desscribes](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Request permission
}
```

Comment: Hai Andrew thank u half of my doubt got cleared. Now I want to check whether user has received the pop up dialog at least once,  because in my scenario user is getting the pop-up dialog twice at a time without user interaction I.e because whenever my fragment is loading it is creating new instance so every time whenever it is loading it is showing that pop up dialog. I want to show that pop up dialog only once when the app has been launched. How can I do the same.